# In TypeScript, how to use Promises with the RSVP implementation on Node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, definitelytyped, rsvp-promise

On Node.js, what is the proper way to use promises with TypeScript ?

Currently I use a definition file "rsvp.d.ts":

```
interface Thenable {
    then(cb1: Function, cb2?: Function): Thenable;
}
declare module rsvp {
    class Promise implements Thenable {
        static cast(p: Promise): Promise;
        static cast(object?): Promise;
        static resolve(t: Thenable): Promise;
        static resolve(obj?): Promise;
        static reject(error?: any): Promise;
        static all(p: Promise[]): Promise;
        static race(p: Promise[]): Promise;
        constructor(cb: Function);
        then(cb1: Function, cb2?: Function): Thenable;
        catch(onReject?: (error: any) => Thenable): Promise;
        catch(onReject?: Function): Promise;
    }
}
```

… and in my ".ts" file:

```
/// <reference path='../node.d.ts' />
/// <reference path='rsvp.d.ts' />
global['rsvp'] = require('es6-promise');
var Promise = rsvp.Promise;
var p: Thenable = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    console.log('test');
    resolve();
});
```

It works but the reference to "global" is ugly.

NB. I failed to use the [definition file from DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/es6-promises).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Proper fix

Just updated the definitions to support the *correct* way : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/2430

So using the same defs (https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/es6-promises) now you can do:

```
import rsvp = require('es6-promises');
var Promise = rsvp.Promise;
```

## Just a suggestion for future

> It works but the reference to "global" is ugly.

You can do :

```
var rsvp = require('es6-promise');
var Promise = rsvp.Promise;
```

Comment: Thank you. About the suggestion, tsc was OK but WebStorm reported (by mistake) an error.